# Why the method getHoldability() is not supported?

Tags: java, sql, function

I am getting this exception while trying to use this method `resSet.getHoldability()`:

exception I get:  `java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`

this is the bit of code interested:

```
Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
    ResultSet setT=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM books");
    System.err.println("HOLDABILITY IS: " +
            ""+setT.getHoldability());
```

I am wondering why `getHoldability()` method is not supported since setting `ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` does not give problems at all.

Comment: This heavily depends on the jdbc driver. Which one are you using?

Comment: the latest available for mysql

Comment: Then ask in the MySQL forum instead. Note that this site is not for specific libraries support.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ahha why did you ask me which one I was using in the first place?

Comment: To tell you where to ask. By the way, I would be surprised if you said that you were using Oracle JDBC driver and they didn't support what they promote =P

Comment: I have a similar question but this time the driver is `HiveDriver`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312944/why-does-not-hiveconnection-support-getholdability-using-c3p0-with-hivedriver