# Why does not HiveConnection support getHoldability()? Using C3P0 with HiveDriver

Tags: jdbc, hive, apache-spark-sql, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am trying to use `C3P0` (`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`) with `HiveDriver` (`org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`).  I got an exception of this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.getHoldability(HiveConnection.java:924)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:106)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:159)
```

I found the source code of `HiveConnection` ([here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveConnection.java))

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 *
 * @see java.sql.Connection#getHoldability()
 */

@Override
public int getHoldability() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException("Method not supported");
}
```

My questions: Why does `HiveConnection` choose to throw an
`SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` ? Instead of just returning one of these?

```
ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT
ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT
```

Is this a bug?

In general, is it possible to use a connection pool such
as `C3P0` with `Hive` (I am actually using `Spark SQL`)?

**Update 1 (2017-11-15)**

I just tried `dbcp2` (`org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`) and it worked.  I guess somehow `dbcp2` does not invoke the `Connection#getHoldability()` method.

Comment: It is technically a bug, because the JDBC specification does not allow a driver to throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` for `Connection.getHoldability()`. But asking us why is asking for guesses. You should file a bug with the authors of the Hive driver.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I filed a bug report HIVE-18082 with Apache: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

( I am answering my own question here.  )

Thanks for the suggestion by Mark Rotteveel, I now also think the problem is indeed a bug.  I have filed a bug report HIVE-18082 ([here](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18082)) with Apache.

Before the bug is fixed, one temporary workaround is to use a different connection pool -- `DBCP2` instead of `C3P0`.  For some reason the former does not make the call of `Connection#getHoldability()` and is thus not affected by this bug in `HiveConnection`

Comment: The issue you files is till open!